# oracle.dataaccess.dll keep showing up as reference after build of C# web service using Oracle MDAC

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, web-services

I am converting a C# Web service from using Oracle.DataAccess to the Oracle Managed Data Access (MDAC) driver.  My understanding is that once I removed all the references to the old Oracle.DataAccess library that the MDAC would no longer need it. I used nuget to upgrade to Oracle MDAC with no errors.  I changed the using statements to use MDAC, and removed project references to the old driver.  Is oracle.dataaccess.dll required for web services?

Every time I do a build of my solution in Visual Studio 2022, the oracle.dataaccess.dll file is magically added back to the references (bin folder).  I cannot see anywhere that I still have a using clause for it or an entry in the web.config.  I have used gacutil to remove it from the gac and it removed 4 versions of it.  When I do a corporate build and deploy and try to run it on our server it fails with a message that it cannot find the Oracle.DataAccess.dll.  Even if the reference is left in place and I copy the dll to the folder the web service resides in.